# How to use std::enable_if with variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a Tensor class (for those who don't know this is the mathematical equivalent of a multi-dimensional array), and I wish to only allow it to compile if instantiated with a type which satisfies certain type-traits.

Ordinarily, I would do something like:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size, typename Enable = void>
class Foo;

// Only allow instantiation of trivial types:
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
class Foo<T, Size, typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivial<T>::value>::type>
{
     // Implement stuff...
};
```

However, I require an unknown number of template parameters to specify the bounds of each dimension of my tensor object like follows:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Sizes, typename Enable = void>
class CTensor;

template <typename T, std::size_t Sizes>
class CTensor<T, Sizes..., typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivial<T>::value>::type>
{
     // Implement stuff...
};
```

However, this doesn't work due to the variadic template parameter `Sizes...`. I wish to be able to instantiate the `CTensor` object as follows:

```
CTensor<int, 3, 4, 5> testTensor; // Compiles fine and produces a rank 3 tensor
CTensor<ComplexClass, 3, 4, 5> testTensor2; // Produces a compile-time error
```

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you use `enable_if` on a class?  It's purpose is to make functions not appear during overload lookup.  If all you want to do is assert that certain conditions are always met, use `static_assert`.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t...Sizes>
class CTensor
{
     static_assert(std::is_trivial<T>::value, "T required to be a trivial type");
};
```

Answer (score 4):

How about not using `enable_if`? This is not what it is meant to be used for (SFINAE). It appears that all you want to do is a static assert:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Sizes>
class CTensor
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial<T>::value, "expecting trivial type blah blah");
};
```