# How do I enable_if a class with variadic template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

Suppose I have a class with the following signature:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class A;
```

But how this class behaves should depend on some other parameter, let's say it's the value of `T::value`:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args, typename Enable>
class A;

template <typename T, typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<T::value>::type>
class A
{
  // do something
};

template <typename T, typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<!T::value>::type>
class A
{
  // do something else
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

However, this program gives the following error:

> prog.cpp:6:11: error: parameter pack ‘Args’ must be at the end of the
>   template parameter list
>        class A;

I have struggled to find a good source of information on the use of `enable_if` to select classes with variadic templates. The only question I could find is this one:

[How to use std::enable_if with variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659013/how-to-use-stdenable-if-with-variadic-template)

But despite the name, this question and its answers aren't much help. If someone could provide or link a guide on how this should be approached and why that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, what you're trying is writing multiple definitions of a class template. That's not allowed because it violates One definition rule. If you want to do conditional enabling with classes, you need *specializations*. Also, the compiler error message already told you, you can't have a variadic parameter pack in the middle of a parameter list.

One way to do it would be:

```
namespace detail {

template<typename T, typename Enable, typename... Args>
class A_impl;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
class A_impl<T, typename std::enable_if<T::value>::type, Args...> {
    // code here
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
class A_impl<T, typename std::enable_if<!T::value>::type, Args...> {
    // code here
};
}

template<typename T, typename...Args>
class A : public detail::A_impl<T, void, Args...> {};
```

[Jonathan's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26421385/947836) is also perfectly fine if the condition is really a `bool`, but it might not be useful if you wish to add more specializations that each depend on several conditons.

Comment: I tried to declare `A<float, int> a;`, but the compiler kept telling me: "implicit instantiation of undefined template `detail::A_impl<float, void, int>`. I'd appreciate it a lot if you can explain this a little bit. (Sorry I'm still learning these stuff).

Comment: @astroboylrx For this to work, the first type in the template parameter list of `A` needs to have a `value` member, because the check in `enable_if` depends on it. You have used `float` instead. Without `value` member, the checks in `enable_if` are invalid, so the primary template of `A_impl` (it has no implementation, it's only declared) gets selected and you get the error.

Answer (score 10):

It looks as though for your purposes you don't need to enable/disable the class, you just need a partial specialization:

```
template <typename T, bool B = T::value, typename... Args>
  class A;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
  class A<T, true, Args...>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
  class A<T, false, Args...>;
```

Comment: I think that using [template alias like here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/524efebedc6a4d1c) is closer to what OP wants

Comment: Yes, it's simple to then wrap that in an alias to make it more user-friendly