# Can I use `enable_if` on a non-type template parameter pack inside the class definition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates

I would like to template a class on a possibly fixed number of bools, count them, and use that number as the template parameter to a base class. Something like this

```
template <int Dimensionality> struct Foo {}; // I want to inherit from this

// helpers to compile-time count the true values among bools
template <bool B, bool... Args>
struct count_true {
  static constexpr int value = count_true<B>::value + count_true<Args...>::value;
};

template <>
struct count_true<true> {
  static constexpr int value = 1;
};
template <>
struct count_true<false> {
  static constexpr int value = 0;
};

// I want something like this, pseudocode
template <bool... Args>
struct Bar : public Foo<count_true<Args...>::value> {
  Bar(bool... args) {
    // do something with the parameters
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) <= 1337);
  }
};
```

But I can't find a way to do this.
There seem to be a lot of questions relating to the use of `enable_if` for parameter packs for functions, e.g.

- [C++ parameter pack with single type enforced in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47470874/2397253)
- [Checking type of parameter pack using enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671643/checking-type-of-parameter-pack-using-enable-if)

Or uses where the template types are not used for inheritance, e.g.

- [How do I enable_if a class with variadic template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421104/how-do-i-enable-if-a-class-with-variadic-template-arguments)

But none of that has helped in this particular case.
The "pseudocode" does not compile because `bool... args` is not an unexpanded parameter pack.

I was thinking something like this might work, but it does not, as the parameter pack must be the last template parameter:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct Bar : public Foo<count_true<Ts..., std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same<Ts, bool>::value && ...), bool>>::value> {
…
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? This question is probably a bit confused, as I really don't know what I'm doing w.r.t. template metaprogramming.

Comment: How are `args...` and `Args...` related to each other?

Comment: I want to express that the constructor should take values of the types given as the template parameters. So if I instantiate `Bar<true, false, false>`, the constructor signature should become `Bar(bool, bool, bool)`.

Comment: A constructor itself could be a template. What about doing `template<std::same_as<bool>... Ts> requires(sizeof...(Args) == sizeof...(Ts)) Bar(Ts... args)`? Also, `count_true<Args...>::value` could be replaced by `(Args + ... + 0)`.

Comment: That also works, would be an alternative answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But none of that has helped in this particular case. The "pseudocode"
> does not compile because `bool`... args is not an unexpanded parameter
> pack.

You can expand template parameters using `decltype()`. Additionally, `count_true` can be simply replaced with fold-expression.

```
template <bool... Args>
struct Bar : public Foo<(Args + ... + 0)> {
  Bar(decltype(Args)... args) {
    // do something with the parameters
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) <= 1337);
  }
};
```

Comment: My bad, for some reason I thought it was invalid.

Comment: Putting the assertion inside class definition - instead of method - leads to better maintenance. Because it doesn't rely on anything specific to the constructor